# How to deserialize XML to different structs based on tag name using serde_xml_rs?

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I am using [serde-xml-rs](https://crates.io/crates/serde-xml-rs) for easy information transfer that I or anyone else can change later without having to code in Rust.

It looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <mass>1</mass>
    <pole_radius>1</pole_radius>
    <eq_radius>1</eq_radius>
    <atmos_n2>1</atmos_n2>
    <atmos_o2>1</atmos_o2>
    <atmos_ar>1</atmos_ar>
    <atmos_co2>1</atmos_co2>
    <atmos_ne>1</atmos_ne>
    <atmos_he>1</atmos_he>
    <atmos_ch4>1</atmos_ch4>
    <atmos_h20>1</atmos_h20>
</root>
```

Which works, but it's kind of ugly and a lot to take in. I want it to be more like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <planetary>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <pole_radius>1</pole_radius>
        <eq_radius>1</eq_radius>
    </planetary>
    <atmos>
        <n2>1</n2>
        <o2>1</o2>
        <!-- slimmed it down so that it saves space for this post -->
    <atmos>
</root>
```

I am not sure how to use `serde_xml_rs` to work with that system. Here is how it is setup right now, which works when it reads the first XML snippet:

```rust
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_xml_rs;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct LevelData {
    mass: f64,
    // more here, again slimmed for the post
}

fn init() {
    let mut file = File::open("Level.xml").unwrap();
    let mut buff = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut buff).unwrap();
    let level_data: LevelData = serde_xml_rs::from_str(&buff).unwrap();
}
fn main() {
    init();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you would do this by mirroring the same data structure in your Rust types:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct LevelData {
    planetary: PlanetaryData,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct PlanetaryData {
    mass: f64,
}
```